# Take care vs care

Tags: grammar

a Situation.
She always nags about me getting a bodyfriend. And it gets annoying.

> That’s because she cares about you and wants you to be a happy.
>
> That's because she takes care about you and wants you to be a happy.

Comment: Please note: "happy" is an adjective, not a noun.  She wants you "to be happy", not "to be **a** happy."

Comment: Both these sentences are incorrect. Should be "to be happy", and "she takes care **of** you"

Answer (score 2):

"Care" has a range of meanings, but here "she cares about you" means "she has affection or fondness for you". Whereas "She takes care of you" means "She is responsible for you/She looks after you". (Not take care about you)

In the context given, "She cares about you..." is the meaning that you probably want.

Comment: To take care of a person or problem  is not to care for a person.